# Alfresco REST Core API find node by path

Tags: rest, lucene, alfresco, cmis

I am developing an Alfresco client based on REST APIs.

But I haven't found a method that allowsto retrieve a node with its path.

```
[ base url: /alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1 , api version: 1 ]
```

Could you tell me how i can do it ?

Comment: Why do you need this? Can you show us an example of the path you want to use in a request?

Comment: @Lista  a
here is an example: pp:company_home/cm:xlsx/cm:template.xlsx

I want to retrive template.xlsx file by its path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will return the noderef as you are expecting from the folder/file path.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        client = new AlfrescoClient.Builder().connect("http://localhost:8080/alfresco", "admin", "admin").build();
        NodeRepresentation node = findNodeByPath("Sites/testsite/documentLibrary/TestFolder/UploadTest.txt");
        System.out.println(node == null ? "null" : node.getName());
    }

private static NodeRepresentation findNodeByPath(String path) throws IOException {
    if (path.startsWith("/"))
        path = path.substring(1);
    if (path.endsWith("/"))
        path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1);
    return findNodeByPath("-root-", path);
}

private static NodeRepresentation findNodeByPath(String parentNodeId, String path) throws IOException {
    String[] pathParts = path.split("/");
    String name = pathParts[0];
    String remaining = pathParts.length == 1 ? "" : path.substring(name.length() + 1, path.length());
    List<NodeRepresentation> children = client.getNodesAPI().listNodeChildrenCall(parentNodeId).execute().body()
            .getList();
    for (NodeRepresentation child : children) {
        if (child.getName().equals(name)) {
            return pathParts.length == 1 ? child : findNodeByPath(child.getId(), remaining);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using AFTS and PATH operator, it should work. You are basically writing a query, not using a specific API method for "find by path". For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "language": "afts",
    "query": "PATH:'/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:swsdp/cm:documentLibrary/cm:Agency_x0020_Files//*' OR PATH:'/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:swsdp/cm:documentLibrary/cm:Budget_x0020_Files//*'"
  }
}
```

Comment: with that I get the parent and with its ID I get the children and I filter them by name.

Comment: You can simply adjust the query to find the document directly, there's no reason not to. One thing I just realized, PATH query won't be transactional, I'm not sure if this is an issue to you.